# In Autoit what is the fileinstall limitation?

Tags: autoit

I am creating a Zip file up to 4GB and using [FileInstall()](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileInstall.htm) but I'm not able to extract and also not able to create a single .exe file.

```
FileInstall("myPath\myfile.zip","DestinationFolderName")
```

Is there a limitation regarding size for the `FileInstall()` function?

Answer (score 0):

`FileInstall()` is not going to unzip your zip archive no matter what the size is. It will only place the zip in the destination. It's only used to include files in the compiled AutoIt script.

Also, if you use a folder name as the destination, you need a trailing backslash (`\`).

I highly recommend reading the entry for `FileInstall()` in the help docs.